# NullPointerException attempting to access Firebase Datasnapshot data in onCreateView of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I just added offline persistence to my app. In the onCreate() method, I have this code:

```
 mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in: " + firebaseUser.getUid());
                valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        myUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                        city = myUser.getCity();
                        username = myUser.getUsername();

                        Log.d(TAG, city);                         
                        Log.d(TAG, username);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };

                mDatabaseReference.child("users")
                        .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
                mDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Could not load content at this time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

`city` and `username` (which are global variables) are printed to logcat as expected even when offline.

But when I try to access either in the `onCreateView` method, I get a `NullPointerException`. Even trying to access the `FirebaseUser` object in the onCreateView method returns null. This is strange since `onCreate()` is called BEFORE `onCreateView()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this can be attributed to the fact that Firebase `ValueEventListener()` works asynchronously.

The `onCreateView()` executes synchronously after the `onCreate()` method. However, because of the asynchronous nature of the `valueEventListener`, there is no guarantee that your global variable has been set by the time the `onCreate()` accesses it - hence the null pointer exception.

Firebase engineers advocate using the retrieved data inside the `onDataChange()` method to guarantee consistency. Maybe you could try that?

Comment: Using this data inside the `onDataChange()` method won't work with something like updating the UI (which is exactly what am trying to do) because all views would be null at this point.

Comment: How about shifting your `mAuthListener` and the data inside it to the `onCreateView()` method? Is that plausible for your use case?

Comment: Retrieving and accessing the data in onCreateView works just fine. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad that I could help.